# Earnings per share of gold ETF

Tags: etf, gold

I understand how EPS is calculated on an ETF like the S&P500 (such as SPY). However I don't understand how it's calculated on a metal ETF, like gold or silver (thinking about ETFs such as IAU or SLV). I see reports about revenues, earnings and EPS on these metal ETFs. How are EPS calculated on a gold ETF?

Comment: It's calculated the same for a gold ETF and an S&P ETF - so how do you think it's calculate for an S&P ETF?